# Are different constructions of an algebraic structure always isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, self-learning, axioms

Any two complete ordered fields are isomorphic (as proved, e.g., in Spivak's Calculus; see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269353/isomorphism-of-dedekind-complete-ordered-fields)).

While I understand this proof, I cannot yet appreciate why it is *necessary*. Given any set of axioms for some algebraic structure, is it not always the case that any two constructions satisfying those axioms are isomorphic? If not, can someone supply a counterexample?

Comment: Eh, vector spaces of dimension 43 and 87 are not isomorphic as vector spaces.

Comment: Is there only one kind of group?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Yes, this answers the question. But add the restriction that they have the same dimension and your example fails. I think this is where the OP is getting at. I know you know this, I'm just putting it out there.

Comment: Any isomorphism is a bijection, so as more general example you just need to take algebraic structures with different cardinalities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually we can't assume that a set of axioms only has one model up to isomorphism. In fact, if a set of *first-order* axioms has just one infinite model, then it is a consequence of the [Löwenheim–Skolem theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) that it has models of all infinite cardinalities. Since all isomorphisms are bijections, it follows that there must be two non-isomorphic models. The reason why this doesn't break down for complete ordered fields is that completeness is a *second-order* axiom: it quantifies over infinite sets of variables ('any bounded increasing sequence has a least upper bound').

However, there are sets of axioms whose models *of a given size* are all isomorphic. This phenomenon is known as [categoricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley%27s_categoricity_theorem). An example of this is unbounded dense linear orders, whose theory is countably categorical (i.e. all its countably infinite models are isomorphic). In other words, if $M$ is a countable set endowed with a dense linear order $<_M$, such that $M$ has no $<_M$-least or $<_M$-greatest element, then $(M,<_M) \cong (\mathbb{Q}, <)$.

Categoricity is a special property held by certain sets of axioms, but certainly not all sets of axioms. Most of the time, you cannot expect categoricity. (E.g. two given groups of a given cardinality, especially when infinite, are typically non-isomorphic.)

Answer (score 4):

Consider, for example, the group axioms. It is **not** the case that any two structures that satisfy the axioms are isomorphic -- in other words, not all groups are isomorphic.

It is a quite unusual property of the axioms for complete ordered fields that they allow exactly one realization up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

The complete ordered field example "cheats", because it implicitly invokes set theory in addition to ordered field theory.

You may find the theory of *real closed fields* to be interesting: it is the theory of complete ordered fields *without* "cheating", and there are many non-isomorphic examples. The smallest example is the field of all numbers that are both real and algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Suppose your only axiom for an algebraic structure with a binary operation * is

1. $\forall$x $\forall$y (x*y)=(y*x).

Two constructions (if I've understood your term correctly) which satisfy this axiom are:

```
1  a  b
a  a  b
b  b  a
```

and

```
2  a  b
a  b  b
b  b  a
```

But clearly these structures are not isomorphic.