# Synthetic Axiomatization - Meaning

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was reading an answer about the construction of the real numbers and there was a mathematical therm that I could not understand.

On that answer they said that the real numbers can be constructed through synthetic axiomatization, what is the meaning of this expression in mathematics?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you read was **wrong**. You **cannot** construct something via any kind of axiomatization. What you can do is to **stipulate** that the real numbers are a collection of objects together with some operations on them such that *as a whole* they satisfy some axiomatization. Of course, when you do so you **cannot assume** that there is such a thing at all! That is why it is a non-trivial fact that there is in fact a model of the standard axiomatization of the reals. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2246530/21820) regarding the two common kinds of axiomatizations of the real numbers (the standard one is the second-order one).

Comment: Thank you, your answer and the link were very useful

Comment: @Beaba: You're welcome! If you feel that my answer has addressed your question, you can accept it by clicking on the tick.