# Do there exist another $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, large-cardinals

Can we find a set other the $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying all the field axioms, order properties and completeness axiom?

By another set I mean, it differs from $\mathbb{R}$ may be in terms of topology, cardinality, etc,.

**Edit**

I am just curious to see some structure which evidently differ from $\mathbb{R}$, yeah topologically we can find, but topological difference doesn't quit a apparent difference in some sense for me. Yeah I understand my question is vague... but I think I let the reader to get the point.

Comment: You can just define another topology on $\Bbb R$... topology is not inherent in a set.

Comment: Related: [isomorphism of Dedekind complete ordered fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269353/isomorphism-of-dedekind-complete-ordered-fields).

Comment: @KennyLau Yeah fine nice,  I think I have to edit my question. I am just curious to see some structure which evidently differ from $\mathbb{R}$, yeah topologically we can find, but topological difference doesn't quit a apparent difference in some sense for me. Yeah I understand my question is vague... but you get the point

Comment: @dxiv so we can't find a set which differs in cardinality

Comment: We speak of "the" reals because if $(R,+,0,\times, 1,<)$ and $(R',+',0',\times',1',<')$ are order-complete ordered fields then they are isomorphic: There will be a (unique) field-isomorphism between them, and it will also be an order-isomorphism.

Comment: We can embed any ordered field  $F$ into a strictly larger ordered field $G$ of the same ( or arbitrarily larger) cardinality, but if $F=\mathbb R$ then $G $ cannot be order-complete.

Comment: so we cant have a bigger order complete field?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet This is not true if we allow one to be non-separate.

Comment: @Stefan. What is "non-separate"?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The absence of a countable dense set.

Comment: @Stefan.What precisely is wrong?

Comment: @StefanMesken No, DanielWainfleet is right - $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) Dedekind complete ordered field. Looking at nonseparable fields doesn't help. The proof has two steps: (1) show that no *non-Archimedean* ordered field is complete (HINT: think about the set of infinite elements). (2) Show that if an ordered field is Archimedean, then it embeds into $\mathbb{R}$ via a unique map (HINT: to each element of the field we may assign the set of rationals $\le$ it ...).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 3):

We can find a set that is not $\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the field axioms and is a totally ordered set, however we cannot find one that is Dedekind complete. Up to isomorphism $\mathbb{R}$ is the only Dedekind complete ordered field, and this is actually its defining property in a significant sense.

The study of *real-closed fields* may be of some interest to you; it is the first widely recognized generalization of the study of $\mathbb{R}$, looking at totally ordered fields with the same *first order theory* as the real numbers. This means that any statement $\phi$ which is true about *elements* of the real numbers must also be true for the *elements* of this other field, $\mathbb{F}$.

Completeness is a topological property of $\mathbb{R}$ and consequently part of its *second order theory*, the theory of *subsets* of $\mathbb{R}$. There are many real-closed fields which are not $\mathbb{R}$ -- the smallest among them is $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, the algebraic closure of the rational numbers, and the largest real-closed field is the Surreal numbers $N_0$. We also have that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\subset\mathbb{R}\subset N_0$, in the sense that there is a strict subfield of $N_0$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and a strict subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which is isomorphic to $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

If you would like to see more examples I construct a proper class of non-isomorphic real-closed fields in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08908, the smallest one appearing in here being $\mathbb{R}$ and the largest being $N_0$ -- this part of the construction begins on page $53$.