# How can it be true both that Complete Ordered Fields are unique up to isomorphism and that anything that can prove Peano Arithmetic is incomplete?

Tags: real-analysis, logic

The real numbers include the natural numbers which presumably satisfy the Peano axioms, I don't know how you could be a strong enough theory to prove the existence of a set that satisfies the Peano axioms but have the axioms be not strong enough to prove its own incompleteness (and presumably if it's not complete, it is not unique up to isomorphism).

Comment: Is it possible that you are confused between "complete" as in "completeness theorem" as a property of logic, and "complete" as in "Dedekind-complete" or "Cauchy-complete" as properties of fields?

Comment: No, I mean in the logical sense, that Complete Ordered Fields are unique up to isomorphism is stated for instance, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269353/isomorphism-of-dedekind-complete-ordered-fields (citing Spivak's Calculus)

Comment: Or here where it is proved that "Let Fb be a complete ordered field. Then there exists an isomorphism of Fb onto the Dedekind field F": https://spot.colorado.edu/~baggett/appendix.pdf

Comment: My confusion is how something could be unique up to isomorphism but (maybe) incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory of $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ is indeed consistent, complete and computably axiomatizable - it happens to be exactly the [theory of real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) - and of course $\mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. However, $\mathbb{N}$ **is not a definable subset of $(\mathbb{R}; +,\times)$**! This prevents the logical complexity of $(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$ from being inherited by $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$: the latter is bigger, but not more complicated.

What is true - and is what you're gesturing at when you write "anything that can prove Peano Arithmetic is incomplete" -  is that if $T$ is any computably axiomatizable theory such that some model of $T$ has a [definable copy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1154042/28111) of $(\mathbb{N}; +,\times)$ then $T$ is not complete, and similarly any consistent computably axiomatizable theory which [interprets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)) the (very weak) theory of [Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) is not complete. But none of that applies here since we don't have definability of $\mathbb{N}$ in $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$.

---

It might be easier to consider a more algebraic example: $(\mathbb{C}; +,\times)$ is algebraically much simpler than $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ despite being a larger field. For example, the set of polynomials (in any number of variables) which have a zero is much simpler to describe over $\mathbb{C}$ than over $\mathbb{R}$. Similarly, while $\mathbb{R}$ has no nontrivial automorphisms at all there are lots of automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ - including ones which  move reals!

Comment: I think what OP has in mind here is a second-order theory, not RCF.

Comment: @EricWofsey Given that they talk about incompleteness, I got the opposite impression - that they're asking why the incompleteness of first-order PA doesn't extent to $Th(\mathbb{R})=RCF$.

Comment: The title mentions "complete ordered fields" and the reals being unique up to isomorphism, though.

Comment: @EricWofsey And the second half of the title is "anything that can prove Peano Arithmetic is incomplete?," which clearly doesn't apply to second-order Peano arithmetic. We'll see whether this satisfies the OP.

Comment: *(That is, I think the OP is mentioning the uniqueness of complete ordered fields to emphasize that $Th(\mathbb{R})$ is a fortiori complete, and confused why that doesn't contradict the complexity of the theory of one of its substructures. I've rephrased my answer to hopefully be clearer.)*

Comment: Your post does demonstrate that my concerns were not inherently justified ($\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ does not imply the theory of the latter proves PA), but I was referring to a system that includes a completeness theorem/least upper bound property, which it seems to me RCF does not?  If I could say what I wanted exactly I probably wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: @WilliamBell The completeness/least upper bound property is not first-order expressible (and you can see this by noting that if it were, we would have a violation of the compactness theorem). The analogue for arithmetic is the *full* (second-order) principle of induction; *second-order* PA is indeed categorical, while first-order PA is not. (Second-order principles like completeness and full induction are quite strong, but second-order logic is terrible to work with; and in particular Godel's incompleteness theorem *doesn't* apply to second-order logic.)

Comment: @WilliamBell And getting back to the first-order setting, you also need to keep in mind the *computability* requirement in Godel's incompleteness theorem: $Th(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$ is complete, consistent, and interprets (first-order) PA, but isn't computably axiomatizable so there's no contradiction.

Comment: I think you've basically addressed everything I've tried to sort out, accepting your answer.